# Python - How to take user input and use that in function

Tags: python, function

Please help me why on executing the below program an error coming on m variable

```
x=int(input("Enter first number"))
y=int(input("Enter second number"))

def multiplication():
 m=x*y
print("Multiplication result"m)
```

Comment: Have you followed any basic Python tutorial?

Comment: Why did you expect anything else?

Comment: no because I have just started

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get ("return") a result (output) from a function? How can I use the result later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052793/how-do-i-get-return-a-result-output-from-a-function-how-can-i-use-the-res)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, you should accept user inputs with `raw_input()`: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/2873538).

```
x=int(raw_input("Enter first number"))
y=int(raw_input("Enter second number"))
```

Please follow a proper [indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) plan with python:

Also, you did not accept the variables while defining your [function](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions), and learn how to use [`print`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15286401/2873538):

```
def multiplication(x, y):
    m = x * y
    print "Multiplication result: %d" % m
```

Finally, to call this function, use:

```
multiplication(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your respobse!  We can't take any user input and use that data in operation of function

Comment: Sorry               can't we take any user input and use that data in operation of function?

Comment: I am actually to create a calculator.

Comment: I edited my answer, yes, you can take user input and pass it to function. In my answer, I am passing user inputs `x` and `y` to the function `multiplication`. Does that clarify your issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot Now I got it the issue was with ' input' and when I replaced it with 'raw_input' it is working fine

Comment: `def multiplication(x, y):
    m = x * y
    print "Multiplication result: %d"  %m `                           In this `%d `is placeholder for numeric or decimal values but what is the use of `%m`?? Because when I am using only m it is showing error?

Comment: Please check the link i provided for `print` in python. Python accepts list of arguments in a tuple followed by `%`

Comment: `% (m, n, o, etc)` or just for one argument, you can use `% m`.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=int(raw_input("enter first number"))
os=raw_input("Enter the sign of what you wanna do +,-,/,*")
y=int(raw_input("enter second number"))
```

Comment: You might consider editing your answer and add at least one line about what your program does. Also, you can write what your problem was in your question and how you solved your problem. You can also accept your own answer.

Comment: Okay I am edited and will remember this forever Thankyou!

Comment: Better, you do rollback, earlier one was better.

Comment: Cam you please tell me how to learn python ? Now I am using youtube as well as python.org

Comment: Check these: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3226704/2873538), [2](http://www.learnpython.org/), [3](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/python), [4](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/), [5](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/) and search on Internet for more. Follow the tutorial which you like and find easy to learn. Or if you like books: check [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1849069) post. Important: check [Python2 or 3](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this if you want to keep it in functions.

```
def input_function():
    x = int(raw_input("Enter first number"))
    y = int(raw_input("Enter second number"))
    return x,y


def multiplication():
    x,y = input_function()
    m = x * y
    print "Multiplication result", m

multiplication()
```

Or like this, in one function. But it doesn't look so pretty.

```
def multiplication(x,y):
    m = x * y
    print "Multiplication result",m


multiplication(int(raw_input('Enter first number')),int(raw_input('Enter second number')))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def r():
    v = int(input("voltage: "))
    i = int(input("current: "))
    resistance = v*i
    return(resistance,'ohms')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.